# String value cannot be assigned through class methods

Tags: c#, string

G'day, I seem to be having a problem with a class variable in my Windows Form Application.

It is a `string` variable in my `Player` class. When I create a `Player` object, I cannot seem to assign a `string` value to the `playerName` variable.

I've manually created my `Get` and `Set` methods and I can't see anything wrong with it.

I've gotten a message a few times that informs me that the string `playerName` isn't assigned and will remain its default value of `null`. I'm not sure why this is the case.

```
class Player
{

    private string playerName = ""; //Variable used for giving each player a unique identifier, eg. 'Player One', etc


    //public string PlayerName { get => playerName; set => playerName = value; }


    public void setPlayerName(string name) //Sets the player's name for the game (UNSC or Covenant)
    {
        name = this.playerName;
    }

    public string getPlayerName() //Returns the player's name
    {
        return playerName;
    }
}
```

Creating a `Player` class and trying to show the `playerName` to a textbox doesn't work, the `playerName` value remains `null`

```
public partial class FrmBoardGameApp : Form
{
    public FrmBoardGameApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ArrayList Players = new ArrayList();

    public void creationOfPlayers() //BUG!!! Values stay null
    {

        Player playerOne = new Player(); //Player 1
        Player playerTwo = new Player(); //Player 2
        playerOne.setPlayerName("Player One");
        playerTwo.setPlayerName("Player Two");

        Players.Add(playerOne); //Player name value is still null at this point
        Players.Add(playerTwo);
    }


    //Here's the textbox assignment code

    public bool playerTurn = true; //A bool variable used to keep track of whose turn it is
    public bool setupCheck = false; // Ensures that the endturn button cannot be hit unless all setup is done
    public int setupCheckValue = 0; //Ensures that the setup button can only be hit once

    public void testingPlayerTurn() //A method used to test whose turn it is
    {
        if (setupCheck != true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Game is not setup, please setup the game");
        }
        else
        {
            //Textbox is empty, as playerName value remains null
            if (playerTurn)
            {
                Players.ToArray();
                Player firstPlayer = (Player)Players[0];
                txtAns.Text = firstPlayer.getPlayerName();
                /*
                 * This method of accessing an element and controlling/manipulating its values works
                 */
            }
            else if (!playerTurn)
            {
                //playerTwo.setPlayerName(factionTwo);
                //txtAns.Text = playerTwo.getPlayerName();
            }
        }
    }


    private void btnEndTurn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Ends the turn of the current player
    {
        changePlayer();
        //testingPlayerTurn();
        testingPlayerNames();
    }
}
```

I've added into the code example some methods that handle player assignment, just in case it helps in any way. But the issue starts at the `creationOfPlayers` method and in the `Player` class.

Comment: I took the libertry to remove code from yoiur post, that is not relevant to your problem, to increase the readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this:

```
public void setPlayerName(string name) //Sets the player's name for the game (UNSC or Covenant)
{
    name = this.playerName;
}
```

should be the other way around:

```
public void setPlayerName(string name) //Sets the player's name for the game (UNSC or Covenant)
{
    this.playerName = name;
}
```

Problem: you actually assigned the value of your field to the local parameter of the method.

Explanation: on the left side of the `=` should be the variable that receives the value, on the right side should be the variable that gives the value (or reference in other cases).

Comment: That will do the trick. Values are assigned from right to left, and `this` revers to the current object you're operating on. So you want to assign the passed value `name` to the property `playerName` in your object, which you reference with `this.playerName`.

Comment: If C# had the feature from C++ to write setPlayerName(const string name), such bugs could be avoided. Since C# 8 developed in this direction (readonly members), let's hope we will get it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In your player class, inside setPlayerName method, you should be asisgning name parameter value to this.playerName. I see you have done reverse

```
public void setPlayerName(string name) //Sets the player's name for the game (UNSC or Covenant)
        {
            //name = this.playerName;
            this.playerName = name;
        }
```

Comment: this is a duplicated answer. I think you should delete this